# Could MonoTouch be used to make a Unity3d plugin

Tags: iphone, plugins, xamarin.ios, unity-game-engine

Could MonoTouch be used to make a Unity3d plugin.  A Unity3d plugin is usually a library. Here is some more info:
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely, or **at least not easily** because:

- MonoTouch generates executables, not static libraries;
- Both Unity3D and MonoTouch embed the Mono runtime - but not the exact same version;
- You cannot host two different Mono runtimes in the same application;
- Even if one could be stripped any small differences in structures could easily crash the whole application;

However it should be a lot easier to share code (C#) or even assemblies (a bit more complex but doable) between the two.